# How to install SimpleSAMLPHP on 000webhost

Tags: phpmyadmin, simplesamlphp

I need to configure my site to consume SAML assertion. I installed SimpleSAMLPHP on a 000webhost site. When I access the site I get 404 error and it looks like the issue is not being able to www folder to public_html folder. Is there a way to configure it to use public_html?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on this page

https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install

I had to modify the files autoload.php and others to reference the files from root directory instead of pblic_html and then it worked